# Applications folder not responding after restoring time machine backup

Tags: macos, finder

I have purchased a new iMac and I got a backup from my old macbook air, I tried to restore this backup file via Time Machine on iMac and already all data transferred successfully but the Applications folder in finder doesn't open also most of programs not working properly.

Hope you got me an answer, thanks.

Comment: Maybe time to reinstall the programs?

Comment: In case of new computer you should use Migration Assistant instead of a backup. This utility will move all your data and programs.